# How to use a 'for' loop with a subset of shuffled data in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, subset

I am trying to do the following:

1. Randomly shuffle my time series
2. Subset the first 5 rows of this data
3. Calculate the Spearman rank correlation for this subset of data.
4. Repeat this 100 times
5. Append each newly calculated correlation into the same csv file.

I feel that a 'for' loop would do this best (but am very open to other suggestions!) so I currently have the following:

```
shuffled= NULL
for (n in 1:100){

  shuffled[n]=mydata[sample(nrow(mydata)),]
  subset[n]<- shuffled[c(1:5),]
  correlations[n] <- cor(subset$col1,subset$col2,, method="spearman")
  write.table(correlations, file="", quote=FALSE, append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)

}
```

Currently, this is giving me the following error message:

```
Error in shuffled[c(1:5), ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

And also a warning message:

```
In shuffled[n] = mydata[sample(nrow(mydata)), ] : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I have been searching for a solution for several hours. I am also not experienced in using loops.  Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

while there are better ways to do execute this,  the key error you are encountering is that `shuffled` should be a `list` not a `vector`.

Then, to index a list, use double brackets, `[[`  (not `[` single)

initialize it as

```
shuffled <- list()
correlations <- list()
...
shuffled[[n]] <- ...
```

Alternatively, if you do not need to keep the shuffled / correlations value, and you are simply outputting to file, I would do the following:

```
correlations <-  lapply(seq(100), function(n) {
                      ## Instead... just sample five directly
                      ## subset <- mydata[sample(nrow(mydata)), ] [1:5, ]
                      subset <- mydata[sample(nrow(mydata), 5), ]
                      cor(subset$col1,subset$col2,, method="spearman")
                    })


## Flatten the list into a single data.frame, then output into
correlations <- do.call(rbind, correlations)

write.table(correlations, ... etc)
```

Comment: Many thanks. I much prefer your suggested method as I do not need to keep 'shuffled' etc. However, I obtain the following error message when running it - I must be missing something obvious. Error in [.data.frame(mydata, sample(nrow(mydata))) : undefined columns selected

Comment: there were commas (`,`) missing after the row-index in the `[`.  I have updated my answer